# how to expendable list enable and disable base on Condition in android

Tags: android

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        groupName = expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition);


    }
});

expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(groupPosition==1)
        {

        }

    }
});

expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {


        if (groupName.equals(childName)) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;


    }
});


expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                        + " -> "
                        + expandableListDetail.get(
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();

        childName = expandableListDetail.get(
                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                childPosition);
        return false;
    }
});
```

[image]

This is my code i want expend enable and disable base on condition

this my screen what i am trying if Parent item name and child item name then i dont want expend if parent item and child item different then only i want please suggest me how to get this coz i  have applied same condition for that but unable to get result

Answer (score 0):

**Do it like this**

expListView.setEnabled(false);

**whenever you want to disable it,when complete then you can call**

```
expListView.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: where we need to apply this condition

Comment: ongroup click you can use position to enable and disable

Comment: its exception coming

Comment: is your group name and child name are same please check on log both name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132989/discussion-between-sunil-chaudhary-and-maklee-lee).